# How can i process the ArrayList with count, and group by function

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

[image]I was process the arraylist of employees, and need the group by function usage by count of employees, count active employees and count inactive employees. I know how to process the total, but how can i process the arraylist with group by function.

```
public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private String department;
    private String status;
    public Employee(String name, String department, String status) {
        this.setName(name);
        this.setDepartment(name);
        this.setStatus(status);
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}

ArrayList<Employee> listEmployee = new ArrayList<Employee>();
listEmployee.add(new Employee("Ravi", "IT", "active"));
listEmployee.add(new Employee("Tom", "Sales", "inactive"));
listEmployee.add(new Employee("Kanna", "IT", "inactive"));

int count = 0;
for (Employee e : listEmployee) {
    count++;
}
System.out.println("Count of Employees" + count);
```

This is the above code i tried to get the count of employees

```
int count = 0;
for (Employee e : listEmployee) {
    count++;
}
System.out.println("Count of Employees" + count);
```

Please help me to process the data by grouping of department

I am expecting the following output to come:

```
Department total activeCount inactiveCount
IT         2     1           1
Sales      1     0           1
```

Comment: Please give ghe code of `Employee` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `stream()` method from the `List<Employee>` to get a `Stream<Employee>` and use the `Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getDepartment)` to group the Employee objects by the department. Once that is done you would get back a `Map<String, List<Employee>>` map object.

The *key* will be the department name and the *value* will be a list of `Employee` objects, now from that list of employees we can further filter the **inactive** and **active** employees:

```
System.out.println("Department total activeCount inactiveCount");
listEmployee.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getDepartment)).forEach((dept, emps) -> {
     int count = emps.size();
     long activeCount = emps.stream().filter(e -> "active".equals(e.getActive())).count();
     long inactiveCount = emps.stream().filter(e -> "inactive".equals(e.getActive())).count();
     int i = 12 - dept.length();
     System.out.format(dept + "%" + i +"s" + count + "%10s" + activeCount + "%10s" + inactiveCount, " ", " ", " ");
     System.out.println();
 });
```

Output:

```
Department total activeCount inactiveCount
Sales       1          0          1
IT          2          1          1
```

It is also advisable to use an *Enum* for the active or inactive status rather than a String.

Comment: i am not getting the desired result, instead i am getting all the three rows

Comment: @cbrak by running the my code? I ran it again it is working as per the expected result.

Comment: if it is boolean type, i am getting the expected result

Comment: @cbrak so you changed `String status` to `boolean status` ? I did it for the former

Comment: no i did for the String status only, i have added attachment, what i have done

Comment: I have added screenshot in the question, what i have tested of your code

Comment: @cbrak we can talk here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197582/room-for-amardeep-bhowmick-and-cb-rak

Comment: @cbrak you are setting `name` in the `this.setDepartment()` it should be `department` that you are passing in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `Map` to group your employees depending of thei departement, then for each departement print the number of employee and the actives one, like this

```
/* for the collector
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;*/

Map<String, List<Employee>> employeePerDep = 
                               listEmployee.stream().collect(groupingBy(Employee::getDepartement));

System.out.printf("%10s %10s %10s %10s\n", "Departement", "total", "active", "inactive");

for (Map.Entry<String, List<Employee>> entry : employeePerDep.entrySet()) {
    int total = entry.getValue().size();
    long active = entry.getValue().stream().filter(e -> e.active.equals("active")).count();
    System.out.printf("%-10s %10d %10s %10s\n", entry.getKey(), total, active, total - active);
}

/* And get : 
Departement      total     active   inactive
Sales               1          0          1
IT                  2          1          1
```

---

**Improvement**

If your `String` for active, can only be `active` or `inactive` you should use a boolean, and make theses changes :

```
//attribute
private boolean active;

//instanciate
new Employee("Kanna", "IT", false);

//count
long active = entry.getValue().stream().filter(Employee::isActive).count();

//getter
public boolean isActive() {
    return active;
}
```

**DEMO** : [`DEMO`](https://ideone.com/Df4nop)

Comment: i understand that boolean will be best fit, but for some reason it is boolean only according to my project

Comment: @cbrak `String` only you mean ? okok

Comment: Sorry, type mistake, Yes, its String Only

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the best approach but you can try this.
Create a **HashMap** with Department as key and value will be a list of employees.

```
HashMap<String, List<Employee>> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, List<Employee>>();
```

Iterate over the **listEmployee** and add all the employees to the hashmap with unique Department.

```
if (!hashMap.containsKey(e.getDepartment())) {
    List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    list.add(e);

    hashMap.put(e.getDepartment(), list);
} else {
    hashMap.get(e.getDepartment()).add(e);
}
```

After creation of hashmap, you simply need to traverse over list in hashmap for every department to get the inactive and active students.

Size of List for every department will give you the total employees in that department.For this you can use this:

```
hashMap.get(e.getDepartment()).size()
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use Map to solve your problem. You can have a **Map< String, List< Employee>>** which will hold "**Department**" as key and all Employee object which belongs to that department as **value**.

Then you will have to iterate over each department's employee list and count active and inactive employee.

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick...

```
List<Employee> listEmployee = new ArrayList<>();
listEmployee.add(new Employee("Ravi", "IT", "active"));
listEmployee.add(new Employee("Tom", "Sales", "inactive"));
listEmployee.add(new Employee("Kanna", "IT", "inactive"));

Map<String, Map<String, List<Employee>>> result = listEmployee.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(Employee::getDepartment, groupingBy(Employee::getStatus)));

result.forEach((department, departmentMap) -> {
    System.out.println(department + ", "
          + departmentMap.size() + ", "
          + ofNullable(departmentMap.get("active")).orElse(emptyList()).size() + ", "
          + ofNullable(departmentMap.get("inactive")).orElse(emptyList()).size());
});
```

Comment: Please avoid "code-dump" answers, as while they *may* help the original poster, they remain completely useless to the primary target of this site: future users with a similar question or problem. Quality matters in questions *and* answers.

Comment: At least offer some decent textual explanation with your answer, meaning a paragraph or two of text, that is not buried within the code as code comments.